# FieldPanel failed to be reflected on content_panels

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am integrating wagtail into my existing Django project.
before integration: file architecture is as below

> |- MyProject/
> __|- templates/
> __|- manage.py
> __|- MyProject/
> ____|- urls.py
> ____|- models.py
> ____|- settings.py
> ____|- views.py

After I installed wagtail packages and reflected that on `settings.py`, **file architecture did not change**. Now I can successfully log in to `localhost/cms/`.

Now I want to customize `content_panel` of CMS admin, hence I defined below class;

```
# MyProject/models.py

class HomePage(Page):
    template = "homepage.html"
    content = RichTextField()
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("content")
    ]
```

then I migrate database and restart web server, but I did not see any change on `content_panels` of CMS admin portal. why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html#start-developing - when you integrate Wagtail into an existing project (rather than using the `wagtail start` project template), the initial homepage created will be a basic `Page` type with no content fields. After you define a real `HomePage` class, you'll need to delete the initial page and create a HomePage type page in its place (along with creating a Site record under Settings -> Sites).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I clearly recalled that I reviewed this statement (replacing with my own HomePage class and setting up a Site pointing to the HomePage) at least 3 times. But I did nothing as I did not understand at all. could you please elaborate that a bit (Why and How)?